# Setting pythonpath for Trac running as fast-cgi

Tags: trac, environment-variables, pythonpath

I have a trac install set up using fast-cgi on a server. I'm trying to install the bitten extension to it so I can do continuous integration - however the environment on which trac is running for some reason *doesn't* have ~/lib/pythonX.X/ in its python path - only /usr/lib/pythonX.X/  this is problematic since I can't install bitten with admin privileges (I don't have them).

What I'd like to do is change the pythonpath of trac so that it does search in ~/lib/pythonX.X/ but I can't figure out where to set or modify this. The trac install obviously doesn't read my .bash_profile so although I can set it there, that's no help.

Has anyone done this before, or can at least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out about ten minutes after posting the question (which was about two hours after starting to try to figure it out)

When dealing with trac as fastcgi, in your trac environment directory there is a file called index.fcgi. This file allows you to set environment variables for that particular trac install.

I simply added

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home/username/lib/python2.4/site-packages
```

as the second line of that file, and things magically started working!